# How to sort string by number?

Tags: c#, sorting

How to sort string by number in string [] ?

```
string[] subdirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("F:/Loveless/data/");
foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
{
}
```

mydata is:

```
1.E/zdssd/dd
2.E/zdssd/dv
3.E/zdssd/sdd
4.E/zdssd/ddsdfsdfdsf
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.E/dfgdfg11
11.
12.
13.
14.
15.
16.
17.
18.
19.
20.
21.
22..
```

that result

```
1.
10.
11.
```

...

```
how to sort 1. 2. 3. 4.
```

**`C# language`**

Comment: You must have tried something! What?

Comment: string[] subdirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("F:/Loveless/data/");

Comment: @monkey_boys - So the data does not love you?

Comment: How does sorting remove "E/zdssd/dd" from the original value "1.E/zdssd/dd". Maybe your question is not about sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort an array using the [Array.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array.Sort.aspx). Assuming that each string in the array matches `^\d+\..*$`, all you need to do is extract the digits, parse them to integers and compare the values:

```
Array.Sort<string>(array, (x, y) => 
    int.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('.'))) - 
    int.Parse(y.Substring(0, y.IndexOf('.'))));
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. ?

Comment: The code works for the examples that you've shown. If your actual data looks different, it's a bit difficult to help.

Comment: I can't see what directories you have on your computer.

Comment: i edit new in question

Comment: change to regex match number?

Comment: Array.Sort<string>(subdirectoryEntries, (x, y) =>
    int.Parse(Regex.Match(x,"\d").Value) -
    int.Parse(Regex.Match(y,"\d").Value));

Comment: Thanks for idea now i can sloved